# I want to access an array inside another array in react native and add it in list view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**My Code is**

```
 <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} renderRow={(rowData) =>
       <CardView cornerRadius={5} style={styles.fabopencard}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.FunctionToOpenDescription.bind(this, rowData.id)}>
              <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}>{rowData.display_name} 
              </Text>
              <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource1}
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} renderRow={(rowData) => rowData.servicedetails.map(servicedetail => {
       <Text>{servicedetail.display_name}</Text>
            })
               }/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </CardView>
   }
   enableEmptySections={true}/>
```

> I want to access an array inside another array

PFB array format:

```
  {   "error":1, "id": 001, "display_name": "demos", "count": 6,   "records":[
   {

        "id": 1,
        "name":"abc",
        "servicedetails":[
        {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        }, {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        }, {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        },
     ]
   }, {

        "id": 1,
        "name":"xyz",
        "servicedetails":[
        {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        }, {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        }, {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2, 

        },
     ]
   }
 ] }
```

I want to access servicedetails array and display it in listview.